# Create running total

Tags: infopath

I'm new to Sharepoint and was wondering if there's a way to create a running total for hours worked. I have an Infopath form set up where the user selects how many hours they spent working on a project in a given week (1-20). Is there a way to add the sum of this field to a running total every week?

Answer (score 0):

Edit the view, one of the options under Group By is **Totals**.

You then be able to 'SUM' the columns placing the value at the top of the view.